# Сложный запрос MySql. 4 таблицы

Tags: mysql

Помогите составить сложный запрос.

В общем, есть 3 таблицы. 
 Контакты, Сделки и задачи

В контактах есть 2 сущности (Клиенты и компании).

```
Клиент связан с компанией (не обязательно)
Клиент связан со сделкой (не обязательно)
Компания связана со сделкой (не обязательно)
Контакт связан с задачей (не обязательно)
Компания связана с задачей(не обязательно)
Сделка связана с задачей (не обязательно)
```

Мне нужно выбрать те контакты у которых нет задачи ни по одной из сущностей.
Допустим, если у клиента нет задачи, но у сделки в которой он состоит есть задача, то выводить этот контакт не нужно. Если у клиента есть компания, у которой нет ни сделки ни задач, то нужно вывести эту компанию.

Написал вот так, но выводит неправильно

```
SELECT c.sid FROM `contacts` c
    left JOIN `link_contacts_leads` lcl ON c.id = lcl.contact_id
    left JOIN `leads` l ON l.id = lcl.lead_id
    left JOIN tasks t ON t.el_id = c.sid or t.el_id = l.sid
 WHERE t.el_id is NULL 

Таблица contacts
id,sid,type,company_id //Если company_id не null, значит у клиента есть компания. type это клиент или компания

Таблица link_contacts_leads 
id,lead_id,contact_id

Таблица leads
id

Таблица tasks
id, el_id //el_id это id контакта или сделки
```

Comment: А зачем вы что то пишите про поле company_id и при этом не используете его в своем запросе. совершенно не ясно зачем оно и с чем оно связано.

Comment: Если company_id не null, значит у клиента есть компания. Связано с contascts.sid

Comment: Т.е. таблица contacts связана сама с собой. company_id может указывать на другой sid, у которого company_id то же может куда то вести. получаем рекурсию, которая на MySQL нормальными средствами вообще не разворачивается. Я не думаю что вам кто то ответит на вопрос в такой постановке. потому как ничего не понятно. нет образцов входящих данных в таблицах и требуемого результата. лучше всего привести пример базы с данными на каком нибудь sqlfiddle.com